# Selecting from Meta.show_sexpr

Tags: parsing, julia, expression

I have expression

```
expr1 = Meta.parse("x=y+(3*x*(d-g))")
```

If I do

```
Meta.show_sexpr(expr1)
```

I get a neet form

```
(:(=), :x, (:call, :+, :y, (:call, :*, 3, :x, (:call, :-, :d, :g))))
```

How do I select from it for example [x,y,3,x,d,g]?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

My favorite way to present AST (abstract syntax tree) is by `using AbstractTrees`:

```
julia> print_tree(expr1)
:(x = y + 3 * x * (d - g))
├─ :x
└─ :(y + 3 * x * (d - g))
   ├─ :+
   ├─ :y
   └─ :(3 * x * (d - g))
      ├─ :*
      ├─ 3
      ├─ :x
      └─ :(d - g)
         ├─ :-
         ├─ :d
         └─ :g
```

If you want to extract variable names you can do (I am still `using AbstractTrees`):

```
julia> filter!(el -> el isa Symbol 
         && !(isdefined(Main,el) && getfield(Main,el) isa Function), 
       collect(Leaves(expr1)))
5-element Vector{Any}:
 :x
 :y
 :x
 :d
 :g
```

Answer (score 0):

The question can be interpreted in different ways. The package [MacroTools.jl](https://github.com/FluxML/MacroTools.jl) contains a number of functions that make it easy to walk the syntax tree and match on different kinds of expression [(docs)](http://fluxml.ai/MacroTools.jl/stable/pattern-matching/).

However, if what you want is to understand the data structure and be able to access specific parts, [`dump`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.dump) can be very useful in general (it's use is not limited to `Expr`, the type you are currently working with).

```
julia> dump(expr1)
Expr
  head: Symbol =
  args: Array{Any}((2,))
    1: Symbol x
    2: Expr
      head: Symbol call
      args: Array{Any}((3,))
        1: Symbol +
        2: Symbol y
        3: Expr
          head: Symbol call
          args: Array{Any}((4,))
            1: Symbol *
            2: Int64 3
            3: Symbol x
            4: Expr
              head: Symbol call
              args: Array{Any}((3,))
                1: Symbol -
                2: Symbol d
                3: Symbol g
```

This means that the first `x` in your expression is: `expr1.args[1]` and `g` is found at `expr1.args[2].args[3].args[4].args[3]`.

More information about this data structure can be found in the Julia manual [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Program-representation).